# How can I specify protocol same name to interface defined in Objective-C from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

When defined as below in Objective-C code, how can I specify Item protocol from Swift?

```
// Objective-C
@protocol Item <NSObject>
@end

@interface Item : NSObject<Item>
@end

@implementation Item
@end



// Swift
var item = Item() // item interface, but I'd like to define as Item protocol.
```

Should I define as distinct name?

Comment: It would be easier when you use 2 different names for the protocol and the class. But it will work with the explicit type like akashivskyy said. variable of type Item and conforms to a protocol also named Item... confusing though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You cannot instantiate a protocol type**, therefore `Item()` will always refer to `@interface Item`. You should explicitly specify that you mean a protocol in your declaration:

```
var item: protocol<Item>
```

---

By the way, the thing you've done in Objective-C cannot be done in Swift – it requires all declarations in the same scope to be uniquely named. Your equivalent, following Apple's conventions, would look like this:

```
@objc(Item) protocol ItemType {

}

class Item: ItemType {

}
```

Comment: Thnaks, but if the class name and protocol name is same, when specifying from Swift, the compiler show the error: "Non-protocol type 'Item' cannot be used within 'protocol<...>'".
Should class name and protocol name is not same if I'd like to refer from Swift?

Comment: In my opinion – yes. Apple renamed its `NSObject` protocol into `NSObjectProtocol` for the same reason.

Comment: Just use `ItemType` or `ItemProtocol` in your Objective-C code and it will become more safe and readable.

Comment: I noticed that, if protocol name and class name is same on Objective-C code, XxxProtocol is automatically generated on Swift code, so I can specify the protocol by using that.

Comment: Oh, that's one more hidden gem I didn't know about, thanks! :)